# php/mysql login system gives errors MySQL Error: ()

Tags: php, mysql

when i run the code i get mysql error() and i get Error in Query Execution.Error : Problem In Executing the Query:

```
insert into kyaami_user_logins set `user_id` = '32', `email` = 'test@test2.com', `ip` = , `timestamp` = NOW(), `state` = 'success', `active`=1
```

MySQL Error: ()

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['msg'] ) )
    {
  if ( $_GET['msg'] == 1 )
    echo "Invalid User. Try Again.";
  if ( $_GET['msg'] == 2 )
    echo "Account Activated Successfully.";
  if ( $_GET['msg'] == 3 )
    echo "Your Account is Locked. contact Administrator.";
  if ( $_REQUEST['msg'] == 4 )
    echo "Mail has been sent to your email address.";
  if ( $_REQUEST['msg'] == 5 )
    echo "Your Account is already activated, Login Here";
  if ( $_REQUEST['msg'] == 6 )
    echo "Your Activation link has been expired, please register again";
     }
?>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="70" align="right" valign="top"><p class="form_text" style="color:#FFF;" align="right"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Email</strong></p></td>
  <td width="410"><div class="form_input_BG"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><p class="form_text" style="margin-left:8px; color:#FFF;"><strong>Password</strong></p></td>
  <td align="left"><div class="form_input_BG"><input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" value=""/></div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong><a href="index.php?page=forgot_pwd" >Forgot your password?</a></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><div class="form_login_signup_btn">
<input title="login Now" type="image" src="images/login_btn.png" name="formSubmit" id="login" width="104" height="33" /> <!--<input type="image" src="images/signup_btn.png" title="Signup Now" name="signup" id="signup" />-->&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="fbconnect.php"><img src="images/fconnect-but.gif" width="89" height="21" border="0"></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="twit_redirect.php"><img src="images/sign-in-with-twitter.png" width="151" height="24" alt="Sign in with Twitter" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div></div>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: `ip = ''` - you forgot to put `''`

Answer (score 0):

It should be **ip = ''**

```
insert into kyaami_user_logins set `user_id` = '32', `email` = 'test@test2.com', `ip` = '', `timestamp` = NOW(), `state` = 'success', `active`=1
```

`ip = ,` is causing the error. correct it to `ip = ''` if value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a blank:

```
insert into kyaami_user_logins 
    set `user_id` = '32', 
    `email` = 'test@test2.com', 
    `ip` = , 
    `timestamp` = NOW(), 
    `state` = 'success', 
    `active`=1
```

If you want to insert a null value use this:

```
insert into kyaami_user_logins 
    set `user_id` = '32', 
    `email` = 'test@test2.com', 
    `ip` = null, 
    `timestamp` = NOW(), 
    `state` = 'success', 
    `active`=1
```

Also, commonly an insert has the following syntax:

```
insert into kyaami_user_logins 
    (`user_id`, `email`, `ip`, `timestamp`, `state`, `active`)
    values ('32', 'test@test2.com', null, NOW(), 'success', 1)
```

This method will survive a change to the table, and you could actually completely skip the IP part by naming the columns (if the default is set to null anyhow) like this:

```
insert into kyaami_user_logins 
    (`user_id`, `email`, `timestamp`, `state`, `active`)
    values ('32', 'test@test2.com', NOW(), 'success', 1)
```

Comment: should i add an ip field on my table?

Comment: @Daniel Now I am confused - if you don't have a field called IP, why were you trying to insert it? You can only insert into columns that exist in the table.

Comment: @Daniel No worries, if your question has been resolved, you should Accept the answer you think most appropriate so that other folks don't keep coming and trying to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any errors like that try to change your code to [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers):

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `kyaami_user_logins`(`user_id`, `email`, `timestamp`, `state`, `active`, `ip`) VALUES (:user_id, :email, NOW(), :state, 1, :ip)");
$stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => 32, ':email' => 'test@test2.com', ':state' => 'success', ':ip'=>''));
```